# Catalan numbers in numerical sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

How to show that the number of sequences of the form ($a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$) when $\sum_{k=1}^i(a_k) \geq i$ for each $i$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k)$ = $n$ is equal to the corresponding Catalan number ($C_n$)?

In my proof that the number of terms of the decomposition of a polynomial of the form

> **$\prod_{i=1}^n(x_1 + ... + x_i)$ is $C_n$,**

I went so far as to be able to show that the number of these terms is equal to the number of sequences ($a_1$, $a_2$, ..., $a_n$) mentioned above

And then I can't find a pattern

Ideas are also accepted to prove my original goal. I will be grateful to everyone

Comment: Are we allowed free reign over all interpretations of Catalan numbers, or do you have some preferred definition(s)?

Comment: @EricNathanStucky, any primitive definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write "$X$" $a_i$ times and one "$Y$" after it for all $i$ from $1$ to $n$. Here are Dyck words, the number of which corresponds to the $C_n$

For example, the set $(2, 0, 1)$ will correspond to two "$X$", one "$Y$", zero "$X$", one "$Y$", one "$X$", one "$Y$", that is "$XXYYXY$"

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the construction I had in mind. (Draw a horizontal line from $x=i-1$ to $x=i$ at height $y=h_i:=\sum_{k=1}^i a_k$, and connecting with vertical lines forms a Dyck path) Just wanted to add that your sequences are closely related to the *area word* common in the study of parking spaces. Definitions vary, but usually it's something like "the number of complete squares in column $i$ between the path and the diagonal" which in my construction would be $A_i = h_i-i = \sum_{k=1}^i (a_k-1)$.